# ¿Como mostrar titulos y contenidos asociados en una consulta de SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Muy buen día.
Necesitaba hacer una consulta en sql server que me pueda mostrar los titulos y debajo de este, sus contenidos. Por ejemplo:

TITULO 1

- item 1.1
- item 2.1
- item 3.1
- item 4.1

TITULO 2

- item 1.2
- item 2.2
- item 3.2

Estoy tratando de hacerlo con una unión, pero lógicamente no me los muestra como lo deseo en el orden que explique anteriormente. Aquí coloco lo que trato de hacer:

```
SELECT
 C.MCC_DESCRIPCION as descripcion

FROM
    OTEC_MATRIZ_EVALUACIONES E
    LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_CONCEPTOS C ON C.MCC_MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION
    WHERE E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=5
union all
SELECT
 I.ITC_DESCRIPCION as descripcion
FROM
    OTEC_MATRIZ_EVALUACIONES E
    LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_CONCEPTOS C ON C.MCC_MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION
    LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_ITEMS_CONCEPTOS I ON I.ITC_MCC_ID_CONCEPTO=C.MCC_ID_CONCEPTO 
    WHERE E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=5
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, o ejemplo, se lo agradeceré.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más común es que no necesites regresar un resultado así desde SQL Server, ya que ese tipo de formato se genera en el front-end agrupando valores comunes. En ese caso, usarías una consulta así

```
SELECT
     C.MCC_DESCRIPCION as Concepto,
     I.ITC_DESCRIPCION as Item
FROM
    OTEC_MATRIZ_EVALUACIONES E
    LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_CONCEPTOS C ON C.MCC_MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION
    LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_ITEMS_CONCEPTOS I ON I.ITC_MCC_ID_CONCEPTO=C.MCC_ID_CONCEPTO 
    WHERE E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=5;
```

Con eso puedes hacer un grupo por concepto y poner item en los detalles del grupo.

De otra forma, necesitas crear algo que funcionará como una *ruta* para ordenar los resultados.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
     C.MCC_DESCRIPCION as descripcion, 
     C.MCC_DESCRIPCION as ruta
    FROM
        OTEC_MATRIZ_EVALUACIONES E
        LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_CONCEPTOS C ON C.MCC_MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION
        WHERE E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=5
    union all
    SELECT
     CHAR(149) + ' ' + I.ITC_DESCRIPCION as descripcion,
     C.MCC_DESCRIPCION + '\' + I.ITC_DESCRIPCION as ruta
    FROM
        OTEC_MATRIZ_EVALUACIONES E
        LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_CONCEPTOS C ON C.MCC_MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION
        LEFT JOIN OTEC_MATRIZ_ITEMS_CONCEPTOS I ON I.ITC_MCC_ID_CONCEPTO=C.MCC_ID_CONCEPTO 
        WHERE E.MEV_ID_MATRIZ_EVALUACION=5
)
SELECT descripcion
FROM cte
ORDER BY ruta;
```

Esta alternativa duplicará la cantidad de veces que se leen 2 tablas y aumentará la cantidad de bytes regresados por la consulta si se quiere asegurar que no se pierda el orden porque necesitaría regresar la ruta. También anularía cualquier posibilidad de agrupación en el front-end y tendrías que hacer más procesos para asignar diferentes formatos a los títulos.